# mysql subquery depending on field value

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement, subquery, conditional-statements

I want to use different conditions depending on a certain field value. 
If for example the value of field1='abc' then field2 should be '123' else field3 should be '456'. My query is much more complex, but the question is whether I could use different conditinons depending on a field value.
Something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE 
  CASE table.field1='abc'
  THEN table.field2='123'
  ELSE table.field3='456'
```

I have a solution for my problem, but it goes with 3 subqueries which takes a lot of time to respond.

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please provide sample data and the desired result, because with your information now I don't understand your problem at all.

Comment: Better check with dynamic query.

Comment: If the three subqueries are needed to do the `WHERE` condition then definitely consider a dynamic query. If they're part of the query regardless of the `WHERE` condition I'd suggest posting your query (and table structures and sample data) as a new question, asking if it can be made more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

> If for example the value of field1='abc' then field2 should be '123'
>   else field3 should be '456'

You don't really need a `CASE` statement here. Rather use different combination of condition like.

```
WHERE (field1 = 'abc' and field2 = '123')
OR (field1 != 'abc' and field3 = '456')
```